# RecyclerViewAdapter in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an array that save different sensors data (in non-activity class) and I want the `RecyclerView` to be updated based on data of that array. Is it possible to automatically change the presented data?

I used `setOnClickListener` but nothing updated. The `RecyclerView` just display the default data. Also, I used text view however the data is updated with each click not continuously.

Thanks for your help.

**In fragment:**

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.buttonStart-> {
                start(v)
            }
            R.id.buttonStop-> {
                stop(v)
            }
        }
    }

    fun start (_v: View) {
        listListSensors.adapter = SensorsRecyclerViewAdapter(model.listSensors(), mListener!!)
    }
```

**In the other class:**

```
   fun listSensors(): Sensors {
        return currentSensor
    }
```

**In recycle view:**

```
class SensorsRecyclerViewAdapter (items: Sensors, listener: ListSensorsFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<SensorsRecyclerViewAdapter.SensorsViewHolder>() {

    private var mValues: Sensors = items
    private var mListener: ListSensorsFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener = listener
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SensorsViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewlistsensors_item, parent, false)
        return SensorsViewHolder(itemView)
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SensorsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.mItem = mValues
        holder.listSensorsLightView.text =  mValues.getLight() 
        holder.listSensorsTemperatureView.text = mValues.getTemperature() 
        holder.listSensorsGyroscopeView.text = mValues.getGyroscope() 
        holder.listSensorsAccelerometerView.text =  mValues.getAccelerometer() 
        holder.listSensorsGravityView.text = mValues.getGravity() 

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener { mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Adapter

```
  var itemClickListener: ((position: Int, name: String) -> Unit)? = null
 fun setData(data:List<AnyList>){
        this.list.clear()
        this.list.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

//bindviewholder

```
itemClickListner.invoke(1,"anyvalue")
```

**// in fragment**

```
    adapter.itemClickListener = { 
                position, name ->
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"position is $position name is $name ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
// call setData()  any place in fragment
```